# Why on change event for TextArea not firing in my ASP.net page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following code in my asp.net page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="upTaskDetailRight" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width: 98%; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="brClear">
            <div class="noteClass brClear">Notes</div>
            <div style="width: 98%; height: 120px;">
                <textarea id="taskNotes" runat="server" class="taskNotes" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-highlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB; scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF; scrollbar-shadow-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #A0A0A0;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnComplete" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Which translates to this HTML source code:

```
<div id="upTaskDetailRight">
    <div style="width: 98%; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="brClear">
        <div class="noteClass brClear">Notes</div>
        <div style="width: 98%; height: 120px;">
            <textarea name="ctl00$ContentMain$taskNotes" id="ContentMain_taskNotes" class="taskNotes" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-highlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB; scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF; scrollbar-shadow-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #A0A0A0;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('change', "#ContentMain_taskNotes", function (e) {
        alert("changing");
    });
});
```

What I am wanting for it to do is, every time I make any changes to the TextArea, it should show me the `changing` alert but nothing is happening when I type or delete anything in the TextArea.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add a handler for `keyup` in addition to `change`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind on `input propertychange` instead. This will alert on every change. The `change` event will fire only when leaving the textarea.

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('input propertychange', "#ContentMain_taskNotes", function (e) {
        alert("changing");
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5zt2z8L/).

Comment: It works outside of an asp.net page but within it, it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: What if you place that generated HTML markup directly in your aspx, does it work then?

Comment: Let me try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this to bind on more than one option

```
 $("#ContentMain_taskNotes").bind('blur change keyup',function (e) {
        alert("changing");
    });
```

of if just for keyup then this

```
 $("#ContentMain_taskNotes").bind('keyup',function (e) {
        alert("changing");
    });
```

[JSflddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afo5gnyy/)

Answer (score 2):

The change event fires when the focus is lost, not when a key is pressed. If you want to detect changes "online" you'll need to use key related events.

```
$("body").on('keyup', "#ContentMain_taskNotes", function (e) {
    alert("changing");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yeg4nkp/)

Comment: I am really having an issue with getting the value of the TextArea from a masterpage, and here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555640/why-updated-textarea-value-inside-an-updatepanel-is-not-shown-and-saved. This was a test I made but wasn't working for me :/ Thank you. I will test it out